# Vector word problem

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having real trouble understanding exactly what's going on in this word problem.  Here is the problem word for word:

A submarine **descends** at an angle of $30^{\circ}$ **below** the horizontal with a heading to the **northeast**.  If its speed is 8 knots, find the components of the velocity in the east, north, and vertical directions.

I know drawing a picture helps, but that's where I'm having trouble.  I can not draw a picture because some of the wording seems to contradict itself.  It says the sub is descending at an angle 30 degrees below horizontal, so it is moving downwards.  Then it says the sub's heading is northeast.  What?!  what does this mean?  In my mind, the sub has a heading of Southeast... Can anyone help me understand what the question means by "heading" and "descending"?

Comment: Descending, going down into the water while heading in a certain direction. If it travelled for a while, then the point on the surface of the ocean directly above it would be northeast of the starting point. The sub is going down at a fairly shallow angle, $30^\circ$ from the horizontal, so $60^\circ$ from the vertical.

Comment: I'm still confused - how could the sub be moving down and up at the same time?  How can it be descending while moving northeast?  To say that a point on the surface of the ocean would be north east of the starting point would assume that the sub was already under water...how can you conclude this from the question?

Comment: Imagine a swimmer in a competition. She dives into the water at a shallow angle, is going down for a while but her horizontal component is towards the end of her lane.  North-east is not up, just go outside and look in a north-east direction. You won't be looking up.

Comment: I see now, I was just stuck in the x-y plane and the problem is in x-y-z dimensions

Comment: Yes, that's it. I figured you had a two dimensional view when you called North-east up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is meant in this way:

[image]"

ABEF is the the water surface.

A->B heads to east

A->E heads to north

your submarine is in A heading to point X

X is somewhere in the middle of FG so that angle FAX = 30 degrees.
The length of AX is 8 knots.

Comment: I didn't realize it is 3d...making north 'horizontal' is confusing, but this makes sense with the question.  Thank you.